# Show that $1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \dots + \frac{x^n}{n!} \leq e^x \leq 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \dots + \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{e^{a}x^n}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Show that if $0 \leq x \leq a$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $$1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \dots + \frac{x^n}{n!} \leq e^x \leq 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \dots + \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{e^{a}x^n}{n!}$$

Let $$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{x^n}{n!} + \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}e^x$$
where $e^x$ is expanded by Taylor's theorem, but I am not sure if I am correctly applying Taylor's theorem because it isn't clear to me where the right side of the inequality comes from.

How does Taylor's theorem get used to complete the inequality? Is that even the right approach to this problem?

[image]

Comment: What follows after "Let" is false. It could be true if you'd put in the last summand $\;e^c\;$ , with some $\;0<c<x\;$ (residue in Lagrange's form). Otherwise you'd need to use the infinite Tylor series. And what "Taylor Theorem" are you referring to?

Comment: $e^x =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} \gt \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!}$ as every term is positive. Then use the fact that $x\leq a\implies e^x \le e^a$.

Comment: @DonAntonio I updated with the taylor's theorem I am referring to edit: sorry my edits are geting messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea: since$\;0\le x\le a\;$ , we have

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\ge \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{ x^k}{k!}$$

and you get the leftmost inequality. On the other hand $\;e^x\le e^a\;$ since the exponential function is monotonic ascending. Now take it from here, or using Taylor's Theorem that you just posted now:

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}+\frac{e^c x^n}{n!}$$

But $\;e^x\le e^a\;$. End now the argument for the other inequality

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor's theorem,
$$
e^x  = 1 + x + \frac{{x^2 }}{{2!}} +  \cdots  + \frac{{x^{n - 1} }}{{(n - 1)!}} + \frac{{x^n }}{{n!}}e^c 
$$
for all $x\geq 0$ with a suitable $0\leq c\leq x$. Now just note that if $0\leq x\leq a$ then
$$
1 \leq e^c \leq e^x \leq e^a .
$$